# Error communicating between BxlServer and client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have been trying to upgrade SQL server 2017 to run Python 3.7. We have installed CU28 and the product version is 14.0.3430.2 which includes the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.INSTANCENAME\PYTHON_SERVICES.3.7.

I have made sure all permissions are granted to the INSTANCENAME directory and pythonlauncher.config working directory is pointing to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData and launchpad service account has permissions to this directory.

I have done all this as an upgrade twice and got various errors, and a clean install. The error I am getting is

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0
A 'Python' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
An external script error occurred: 

Invalid BXL stream
error while running BxlServer: caught exception: Error communicating between BxlServer and client: 0x000000e8
```

HRESULT 0x000000e8 looks like INVALID_CANCEL_OF_FILE_OPEN

HRESULT 0x80004004 looks like E_ABORT

So no real clues what is wrong here. pythonlauncher.log does show the error;

```
[Error] Process::TryTerminate failed with error code: 5
Session 0E93E9D1-07A7-448A-8B1A-FCA5263A5F53 TryTerminate(1067) failed with 5
```

Error code 5 is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
Also got this warning

```
[Warning] StaleDirectoryCleaner() failed to delete C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\FAMSQL17UAT01\8B97815A-E9EA-4FA0-98F3-0440D4180522 after 5 retries
```

So all up this looks there are still permission issues. Extremely frustrating as there is next to no help on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

After another clean install - first checked Python 3.5.2 worked and it did. Upgraded to 3.7, and again got the same issue. A bit more digging around I find this...

```
The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/SERVERNAME.domain_name.com:INSTANCENAME ] 
Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVERNAME$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.
```

We have a service account that is not part of the domain which is NT Service\MSSQL$INSTANCENAME. Why on this implementation expecting a windows authenticated user the same name as the server??? How can I go about remedy this?

I think what has happened is that MS have left debug code in their production release.

FURTHER UPDATE:

In the event log we are seeing

> Faulting application:Python.exe: 3.7.1150.1013 Faulting module name:
> pylink.pyd Faulting module path:c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL14.INSTANCENAME\PYTHON_SERVICES.3.7\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\rxLibs\pylink.pyd

Comment: did you try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/troubleshooting/known-issues-for-sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15#3-failure-to-initialize-a-varbinary-variable-causes-an-error-in-bxlserver

Comment: Yep. Nothing helpful.

Comment: I have that error too even when I execute a simple script such as print(3*3). I'm on SQL server 2017 CU28, it used to work with python 3.5.2 before updating to CU28, but I decided to update in order to get python 3.7.2, but it doesn't work, every script raises "Invalid BXL stream". I think it'd be better if we open an issue on the github page https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues

Comment: Glad to know that it is not just me. I did open up an issue on github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues and got told that this is a production issue and was told to log this issue with Feedback (which I have done). You can upvote me if you like... https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/7d764ae0-f78d-ec11-a81b-0022484bfd94. Typical Microsoft bouncing the issue around rather that taking ownership.

Comment: I just upvoted it, hope a solution will be presented soon

Comment: I don't know how but now Python version on SQL server is 3.7.11 instead of 3.7.2 and there is no more the BxlServer error, however I had to downgrade pandas from last version to 1.1.5 otherwise when executing the procedure I was getting ImportError: cannot import 'Panel' from pandas

Comment: How did you get that update? We have installed CU28 (latest) - 13 Jan 2022. Just checked the installed python version and it is 3.7.1

Comment: We have CU28 too (recently installed), I ran import sys, print(sys.version) in sql server management studio and got 3.7.11, however I don't know how it is possible, maybe it is just a visual bug. With CU28 we should have 3.7.2 (it is written in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/change-default-language-runtime-version?view=sql-server-2017) so even your 3.7.1 isn't correct, is it?

Comment: Also experiencing this issue with CU28.  Have python 3.7.1 installed with it. Hopefully a solution presents itself soon!

Comment: I have lodged a service request from MS.... Hopefully that can find this issue quickly...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have confirmed that this is a bug. Their work around is below.

1. It's CU27 and CU28 that 3.7 is broken in - so you could use CU26 and still use Python 3.7. That version started at CU22... so CU22-26 work fine.
2. Or - it's only the pylink.pyd that is broken - you can simply grab the pylink.pyd from a CU22-26 installation for Python 3.7, and swap it into your CU27/CU28 files. This workaround will work now, and will also not cause any issues going forward once the fix does come. That is, on your next update, it shouldn't interfere and it should all go smoothly.

Comment: finally a solution many thanks! p.s. by the way are you working with neural networks (keras package) in sql server?

Comment: Not at this stage - but I have a project coming up shortly requiring NN and have not decided on the tech for it...

Comment: Ok, so let me tell you if you will work with keras don't lose time trying to use pickle to save your NN in a sql table as a binary object (as shown here https://microsoft.github.io/sql-ml-tutorials/python/rentalprediction/step/3.html) because pickle is not able to load a keras NN from a binary object. Instead, just save your model as a file somewhere using the usual `model.save(path)` and next load it with `keras.models.load_model(path)`